# How to remove an Array Generic object Sack in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

So, I am creating a generic data structure named "Sack". In this I add items to a sack, grab a random item, see if it's empty, or dump out its contents etc. Also I'm creating it to expand to hold as many items as needed.

The remove helper method should remove the item in the underlying data structure at the
specified index. It should do so by replacing it with the "last" element in the underlying array.
It should also ensure that any unused elements are nullified.

Currently, I'm working on the remove method and I'm having troubles on my remove method. I am receiving errors when I run my tests saying it does not have the correct modifiers. Therefore my code is

```
public class Sack<E>
{
public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private E [] elementData;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack()
{
    elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack(int capacity)
{
    if(capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
    }
    this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void add(E item)
{
    int index = size++;
    if(size >= elementData.length-1)
    {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
    elementData[index] = item;
}
  public E [] dump()
{
   E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      elementData[i] = null;

   }
   size = 0;
    return E2;
}
```

I receive the error in my remove right here

```
 public void remove(int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < size; i++)
    {
        elementData[i] = elementData[i + 1];
    }
    size--;
}
}
```

The value it is expecting to receive is 2, however what it's receiving is 1. Drop down any ways of ensuring this.

So here are my tests. I cannot modify my tests, only my code. 
I receive an error on the first line. I will comment it, so you can see.

```
@Test
public void testRemove()
{
    assertEquals(2, remove.getModifiers(), "remove does not have the correct modifiers"); // I receive an error here. 
    try
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Integer[] setElementData = new Integer[10];
        ArrayList<Integer> expectedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int randElement;
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            randElement = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
            setElementData[i] = randElement;
            expectedElements.add(randElement);
        }
        elementData.set(s, setElementData);
        size.set(s, 10);

        int randIndex;
        int numEe;
        while(!expectedElements.isEmpty()) {
            numEe = expectedElements.size()-1;
            randIndex = rand.nextInt(expectedElements.size());
            expectedElements.set(randIndex, expectedElements.get(numEe));
            expectedElements.remove(numEe);
            remove.invoke(s, randIndex);
            assertEquals(expectedElements.size(), size.get(s), "remove is not working correctly (check size usage)"); //Error now takes place here. 
            for(int i=0; i<expectedElements.size(); ++i) {
                assertEquals(expectedElements.get(i), ((Object[])elementData.get(s))[i], "remove is not working correctly (sack array element order incorrect)");
            }
            assertNull(((Object[])elementData.get(s))[expectedElements.size()], "remove is not working correctly (sack array element not nullified correctly)");
        }
        assertEquals(0, size.get(s), "remove is not working correctly (check size usage)");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("remove is not working correctly");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the full text of the error message and paste it here?

Comment: @NormR it says that the remove does not have the correct modifiers ==> 
Expected :2
Actual   :1

Comment: What happens if `index` - the parameter in method `remove` - is negative? What happens inside the `for` loop in method `remove` when `i` is set to `(size - 1)`?

Comment: Please post the actual error message. 2 and 1 are not modifiers.

Comment: Include your ```set``` method

Comment: @Mark I don't have a set method. I have an add method and ensureCapacity (Which is still invalid, I have a whole other question for that if you'd like to check that out). I will include my add method since that's already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It finally passed all of the tests, although, this was very difficult. Here's the code:

```
private void remove( int index)
{
    if(index >= 0)
    {
        E last = elementData[size - 1];
        elementData[index] = last;
        elementData[--size] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will keep the order:

```
public void remove(final int index) {

    if (index >= size || 0 > index) {

        // TODO better to throw 'new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index)'
        // when remove illegal index
        return;
    }

    if (index < size - 1) { // move whole array

        System.arraycopy(
                elementData, index + 1, // copy from
                elementData, index, // copy to
                size - index - 1); // copy length
    }

    elementData[--size] = null;
}
```

Comment: This is the best code I've received so far thank you, however, I received an error when running my tests. It states assertEquals(expectedElements.get(i), ((Object[])elementData.get(s))[i], "remove is not working correctly (sack array element order incorrect)"); It's under my tests, you can search for it. It's there. How could I fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally figured it out down below, Check out my ensureCapacity question and Grab method questions. They all tie in together.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with:

```
public void remove(int index)
{
    if(index >= 0) {
     E last = elementData[size - 1];
     elementData[index] = last;
     size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP implements a Sack, not a stack

Comment: @Stas yes it's Array of Objects. Also, do I keep my for loop in there? I do right, or else I would receive an error with the elementData[i] in there.

Comment: You don't need your for loop there. Just move the last item to it's place and decrease size by one.

Comment: @Lino it accomplishes exactly what the OP specified. It doesn't make sense, but it's what he said he wants.

Comment: @Stas if there's no loop, what would I do with the 'i' inside the elementData then?

Comment: It’s a typo, I have fixed it. Use index there.

Comment: @Stas alright, makes sense. Let me just clarify the remove method should remove the item in the underlying data structure at the specified index. It should do so by replacing it with the "last" element in the underlying array. It should also ensure that any unused elements are nullified. I'm still receiving an error that the modifiers are wrong when I run my tests.

Comment: @Stas I will posts my tests in hopes that it clarifies it more.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used your method and finally figured it out. I posted my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the modifier of your `remove` variable is not of modifier type `private`.

``getModifiers()``` method returns and int value of the type of modifier. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier) for more info.

Since your assert function asserts that the modifier should be `2` then you should change the class modifier to `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of solving this, a little more simpler.

```
private void remove(int index)
{
    elementData[index] = elementData[size-1];
    elementData[size -1] = null;
    --size;
}
```